# Populating array with disk volume names on OSX - with spaces

Tags: php, macos, command-line, sed, osx-mavericks

Right now I'm using the command below to get the volume names of the mounted disks in OSX:

```
$exec = "df -lH | grep \"/Volumes/*\" | tr -s \" \" | sed 's/ /;/g'";
```

And parsing the output using this code:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $output);
$i = 0;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$driveinfo = explode(";", $line);
$driveinfo[7] = trim($driveinfo[0]);
if (!empty($driveinfo[0]))
$allremovabledrives[$driveinfo[0]] = $driveinfo;
$i++;
}
```

This works fine if the Volume label doesn't have spaces in it:

```
[/dev/disk1s1] => Array
    (
        [0] => /dev/disk1s1
        [1] => 32G
        [2] => 31G
        [3] => 674M
        [4] => 98%
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => /dev/disk1s1
        [8] => /Volumes/LUMIX
    )
```

But if I mount a disk with a volume name that has spaces, disaster strikes and extra array values get added:

```
[/dev/disk4] => Array
    (
        [0] => /dev/disk4
        [1] => 4.0T
        [2] => 1.2T
        [3] => 2.8T
        [4] => 29%
        [5] => 140741078
        [6] => 347553584
        [7] => /dev/disk4
        [8] => /Volumes/My
        [9] => Passport
        [10] => Pro
    )
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem? I'm not well versed in sed and command-line utilities ...

Comment: using a series of explode() functions with "\n" and ";" - which works just fine with volumes without spaces - but of course the command I used creates problems if that's not the case. So I was wondering if the command could be adjusted so that it doesn't create the extra ";" in the volume name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the volume name is always the last field, and you know how many fields there are (9), so I would just split on whitespace and ask for that many fields.  And not bother with any `sed`/`awk`/`grep`/`tr` stuff since you're already in a full-fledged programming system that can do what those commands do more efficiently within its own process space.

First, you can pass the list of volumes you want info about to `df` as arguments, which means you don't need the `grep`:

```
$df = shell_exec('df -lH /Volumes/*');
```

Now split on newline and get rid of the headers:

```
$rows = explode("\n", $df);
array_shift($rows);
```

Start building your result:

```
$result = array();
```

Here's where we don't need to use shell utilities just to make it possible to do with `explode` what we can already do with `preg_split`.  The regular expression `/\s+/` matches 1 or more whitespace characters in a row, so we don't get extra fields. The limit (9) means it only splits into 9 fields no matter how many more spaces there are - so the spaces in the last field (the volume name) get left alone.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $cols = preg_split('/\s+/', $row, 9);   
   $result[$cols[0]] = $cols;
}
```

After all that, `$result` should look like you want.

Comment: Hi Mark, nice suggestion - and I just tried to do it that way. However I'm running into problems - seems that just using the command in terminal works fine. But when I shell_exec() it, I don't see any output, and get error messages. Trying to find out why, since it's very strange that other shell_exec commands work fine.

Comment: two small typo's in your code: $cols = preg_split('/\s+/', $rows, 9)); needs to become $cols = preg_split('/\s+/', $row, 9);